# IIS 7.5 - Access to the Path ... is Denied

Tags: iis-7.5, novell

I am trying to access a static file on a Novell file server.

The drives are mapped on the IIS box. The application is using the the default application pool.

The path (not shown in Title above) is : \cms1\vol4\cms\008\docs\008\2011\Nov\0224294.pdf

If I enter the above path from the command line on the IIS box, it opens the PDF just fine. When accessed via IIS, I receive the error shown in the Title above.

I have researched numerous threads looking for an answer. Most of them suggest changing the properties of the application pool. I have modified it to use my User ID and Password, and confirmed this is the case by checking w3wp.exe, and it shows as running with my user ID. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than change the account the application pool runs under, have you tried adding permissions ("read", and "modify" if appropriate) for IIS_IUSRS to the directory?

Comment: Actually, our system administrator has already added IIS_IUSRS to Novell and given full access to that user. How do I provide the password for that user to IIS?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it looks like I didn't understand your question completely. I was concerned with you possibly giving excessive permission to the IIS app pool by using your credentials. Is the network using Active Directory? Someone with knowledge in that field would likely know how to set it up correctly.

Comment: We are in the process of moving to Active Directory. We ran Wireshark on the IIS server to analyze the request sent to the novell box, and it appears that the request is not even making it out of IIS to the network. Since we are pressed for time, I have opted to retrieve the file via ftp. Thank you for you time. It is appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome :) I suspect the request doesn't get out of the box because the account the app pool is running under doesn't have network access rights, if that's any help in your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have CIFS enabled?  If it is just using NCP, then is Client32 installed on that machine so that NCP access will be enabled?

If you enable CIFS on the Netware or OES server then there is no need for Client32 on the IIS server.  In either case, the service needs to try to connect to the share as a user with sufficient rights.  I imagine the IIS_IUSRS account is not existing in the eDirectory tree.

Comment: Client32 is installed on the Server and the drives are accessible via Explorer. The IIS_IUSRS account has also been added to eDirectory. Thank you for your suggestions.